# React js : Rendering multiple index html in a single page applications

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nodes, e-commerce

I am developing an E - Commerce website in React and Node.js. I am facing two problems described below.

1. I have two different master `.html` files for admin side and front end side. Hence I am using builtin React admin template in which `index.html` is loading on project start. My problem is how can I load another master `.html` for front end design?
2. I want to use Node.js as the back end. Hence I can not integrate node.js with React front or admin side which will run if the React application runs.

Any suggestions or solution steps will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Make a higher level index page as the top level and convert both of your current "top level" pages into children of that one.

Comment: You could also use separate divs as ReactDOM.render targets in your index.html page, 1 for each page.

Comment: @DovRine thanks for response, any example or sample code?

Comment: Btw, you can run more than 1 node server if you use docker or virtual machines.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very basic concept of the first idea:

```
const AdminIndexPage = children => (<section className="AdminIndexPage">{children}</section>)

const PublicIndexPage = children => (<section className="PublicIndexPage">{children}</section>

const App = props => {
    if(props.indexPageToShow === 'admin'){ 
        return <AdminIndexPage {...props} />
    }else{
        return <PublicIndexPage {...props} />
    }
}
```

Here's a very basic concept of the second idea:

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
      <div id="AdminPageIndex"></div>
      <div id="PublicPageIndex"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
import {AdminPageIndex, PublicPageIndex} from './pages'

ReactDOM.render(AdminPageIndex, document.getElementById('AdminPageIndex'))

ReactDOM.render(PublicPageIndex, document.getElementById('PublicPageIndex'))
```

Comment: No I want to render components in two different html with different scripts.

Comment: subdomains with different web roots in 2 different projects? I guess I don't understand what you're trying to do them.

Comment: Actually I will have two different html template with different design , one for admin dashboard another for front end dashboard . There will be two different designed html but so far I know react can load anything of component into a single html template. Hence I am facing the problem.

Comment: my idea 2 addresseses your ossue

Comment: @DovRine It seems I've ended up with the same issue and just seen this post now. Before I will go deep in this I just wonder that if it is the best practice to use your second solution for this issue. I need a admin panel and going to use AdminLTE template for that. I just don't want to use admin related CSS and Scripts in remaining frontend single page.

Comment: In practice, most people make separate landing pages for each application, possibly even with different git repos. This isn't usually a problem bc the api has separate endpoints. I was trying to specifically answer ops question with that solution, but it's probably more trouble than it's worth.